# Custom class, adding child to child-list and throwing exception

Tags: c#, exception

Example code:

```
  public class ElementList
  {
        // some code...

        public ElementList (Element owner)
        {
              // some code...
        }

        public void Add (Element e)
        {
              if (e == owner) // cannot add child which will be self-parent
              {
                    throw new SomeException (); // main problem here
              }

              childList.Add (e);
        }
  }
```

Now what kind of exception I should throw? And if you suggest custom exception, please tell me a good name for it.

Comment: Think about: `MoveNext` if objects of a collection are modified after the enumerator is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short:** `ArgumentException` will do the trick. However, it is not a good practice to throw exceptions that you may easily managed in your code.

I would suggest to rewrite your code like:

```
public void Add (Element e)
        {
              if (e != owner)
              {
                  // Not the owner, do your operation
                   childList.Add (e);
              }
              else {
                    // Log error message or display warning to user
                 }              
        }
```

However, if you **would like to proceed with exception scenario**, then the code will probably look like:

```
if (e == owner) // cannot add child which will be self-parent
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Can not add child which will be self-parent");
}
```

**Edit:** As a reference you may of course use the [**MSDN article**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx)  for detailed understanding.

Comment: Thx for log suggestion, but I have a reason to throw exception here anyway.

Comment: Ok, no problem, i have added a sample code for that scenario as well :)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx).  It would be best to subclass it and make your own - something like ParentElementArgumentException would be a clear enough name - so you can test for this specific condition as well as a general arg exception (like somebody passing in something other than an element).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest `ArgumentException` since the exception will be caused by your argument `e`

```
if (e == owner) // cannot add child which will be self-parent
{
    throw new ArgumentException(/* Include more exception details here */);
}
```